# HTML class not updating after a method completes in .ts file

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I have the following html file that displays an image of google maps.

```
<div class = 'Pick' >
    <ion-img class='location-image' [src]="selectedLocationImage" > </ion-img>
</div>
```

and on the the ngOninit I call the following methods that are supposed to update the selectedLocationImage string.

```
   latitude: any;
  longitude: any;
  selectedLocationImage: string;
  ngOnInit() {
 this.getlocation(this.deviceinfo.currentdevice).then(response => {this.createPlace(this.latitude, this.longitude); }).catch(err => {});
}
```

after this method has completed the selectedLocationImage has been succesfully updated but the image on my page does not refresh at all. This method does take a second or two and this is why I believe the image is not updating in the HTML file. How can i set the html to constintely monitor the selectedLocationImage string and update the ion-inage accordingly?

If i simply set a defualt selectedLocationImage at the astart it works fine but when the method does it, it takes a few seconds and then it does not refresh

Edit: Here is the createPlace method as requested.

```
private createPlace(lat: number, lng: number) {
const pickedLocation: DeviceLocation = {
  // tslint:disable-next-line: object-literal-shorthand
  lat: lat,
  // tslint:disable-next-line: object-literal-shorthand
  lng: lng,
  address: null,
  staticMapImageUrl: null
};

this.isLoading = true;
this.getAddress(lat, lng)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(address => {
      pickedLocation.address = address;
      return of(
        this.getMapImage(pickedLocation.lat, pickedLocation.lng, 14)
      );
    })
  )
  .subscribe(staticMapImageUrl => {

    pickedLocation.staticMapImageUrl = staticMapImageUrl;
    this.selectedLocationImage = staticMapImageUrl;
    this.isLoading = false;
    this.locationPick.emit(pickedLocation);
  });
}
```

Comment: What's your change detection strategy?

Comment: Could you post the code of this function this.createPlace(this.latitude, this.longitude)?

Comment: @NikNik There we go i added the code for you

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is placing `*ngIf` structural Directive on the parent div like this:

```
<div class = 'Pick' *ngIf="selectedLocationImage">
   <ion-img class='location-image' [src]="selectedLocationImage" > </ion-img>
</div>
```

so that the whole parent with image doesnt render unless there is a value.

what is happening is that you trying to map `undefined` to the src of image and it not updating if the field updates.

Comment: Hi the image is still not displaying. The selectedLocationImage does change but the image does not show up

Comment: and it does work when you set it as initial value !?

Comment: you also can use Renderer to listen nativeElement's changes. and that is another way to do that and still pretty good way through a custom directive

Comment: try doing this `<ion-img [src]="selectedLocationImage || ''" > </ion-img>`